# Adding a dimmer switch for led cabinet lights to existing circuit

Tags: kitchens, led, dimmer-switch

I have a single light switch that controls the overhead lights in my kitchen. I want to install new LED strip for my kitchen cabinets and have them controlled from a new dimmer switch next to the existing light switch.

Upon opening the existing light switch I see three 12/2 cables. All neutral wires are capped to a wire nut. All ground wires are bundled to a wire nut, with one of the longer wires running to the ground screw on the light switch. The hot wire from the panel is screwed to one of the terminals on the light switch. The other two black wires are capped with a wire nut that then has a pigtail running to the second screw on the light switch.

How would I connect a dimmer switch to this configuration that would only control the LED strip for the cabinets? Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Is this LED strip in addition to the existing lights, or do you want to replace one of the current lights with the LED strip?

Comment: What do you need to provide for the new lights? Most these days are plug-in type, so do you plan on adding an outlet somewhere? Please revise to make your plan more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  If your skill level is limited to removing the faceplate, then there are 2 good options:

- Get a book about home wiring and start studying.
- Hire an electrician.

Keep in mind that adding a new light switch may require an electrical permit from the local government.